# Derivative of Vectorization of matrix products w.r.t. a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectorization

Suppose $\lambda \in l\times1 $， $ y \in l\times 1$，$A \in l\times mn $， $L \in m\times r $，$R \in n\times r $

$f=1/2 \parallel L\parallel_{F}^{2} +  \lambda^{T} (y-A \text{vec}(LR^{T}) )$

I want to calculate the minimum of $f$.

So, how can I calculate

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial L} $ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial R} $

I am confused with the derivative.
Can someone tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
This product can also be applied to vectors by treating them as rectangular matrices (set $\,n={\tt1}$) in which case it corresponds to the usual dot product.  The cyclic property of the trace allows the terms in such products to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
B:C &= B^T:C^T = C:B \\
B:C &= {\rm vec}(B):{\rm vec}(C) \\
}$$
Note that terms on the RHS and LHS of the colon must have *identical* dimensions.

Use ${\rm devec}$ to denote the reverse of the vec operator
$$A={\rm devec}(a) \quad\iff\quad a={\rm vec}(A)$$
For ease of typing, define the matrix
$$M = {\rm devec}(A^T\lambda)$$
Write the objective function using the above definitions,
then calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac 12L:L - \lambda:\Big(A\,{\rm vec}(LR^T)-y\Big) \\
   &= \tfrac 12L:L - A^T\lambda:{\rm vec}(LR^T) - \lambda:y \\
   &= \tfrac 12L:L - M:LR^T - \lambda:y \\
df &= L:dL - M:(dL\,R^T+L\,dR^T) \\
   &= (L-MR):dL - M^TL:dR \\
}$$
Holding $R$ constant (i.e. setting $dR=0$) yields the gradient with respect to $L$, while holding $L$ constant yields the gradient wrt $R$.
$$\eqalign{
\p{f}{L} = L-MR, \qquad \p{f}{R} = -M^TL \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and if I futher choose penalty function$$ f=1/2 \parallel L\parallel_{F}^{2} + \lambda^{T} (y-A \text{vec}(LR^{T}) )+1/2\sigma\parallel y-A \text{vec}(LR^{T})\parallel_{2}^{2}$$, what are$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial L} $$and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}$$？